# How to filter out "bad" URLs from the "good" URLs? (in Google's eyes)

Tags: php, hyperlink, google-api, httprequest, adsense

I let users post links on my website. Obviously I want to filter out harmful links (such as pornography links) so I do not get cited by Google (since Adsense does not allow pornographic/etc... material).

I'm trying to use Google's Safe Browsing API, but it seems like that it only filters out phishing/malware links (and I couldn't get the http requests via my server to work anyway).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a small table of unacceptable words to autofilter + blacklist websites would work. If you spend the extra effort to make it intuitive it would start to build its own blacklist.